# Python adding numbers from many files without using so much memory

Tags: python, loops, file

I have written a python script, which works perfectly (see below). the code read lines from different input files and try to do some calculations. The input files looking like following:

```
Timestep 1000
Y TESFG
1.5
1.3
1.2
1.8
Timestep 1001
Y TESFG 1
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.2
Timestep 1002
Y TESFG 1
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.2
```

and so on....

the main output file (varaible sed) is in the same format like following:

```
Timestep 1000
Y TESFG
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
Timestep 1001
Y TESFG 1
2.0
2.0
2.0
2.0
Timestep 1002
Y TESFG 1
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.2
```

I wanted to have the summation of the variable "sed" for all timesteps in one outputfile. I have used append to make a new list and calculate the addition for each line but my files are so big and it takes too much time to use append.

can you please give some tips how can I add each numbers under timestep with each other so that the result looks like this:

```
Timestep all
Y TESFG 1
4.0
4.0
4.0
4.2


with open('a.dat', 'r') as v1, open('b.dat', 'r') as d2, open('st.dat','r') as st3 , 
open('v.dat','r') as A, open('sch.txt','w') as outfile,  open('pro.txt','w') as outfile2, 
open('Sed.txt','w') as outfile3, open('Sed.txt','w') as outfile4:
    for line1,line2,line3,line4 in zip(v1,d2,st3,A):
        try:
            line1 = line1.strip()
            line2 = line2.strip()
            line3 = line3.strip()
            line4 = line4.strip()
            column1 = line1.split()
            column2 = line2.split()
            column3 = line3.split()
            column4 = line4.split()
            v1 = float(column1[0])
            d2 = float(column2[0])
            if d2==0.00:
                d2=0.01
            st3 = float(column3[0])
            if st3 > 100:
                st3=100
            Sch = 1000*9.807*d2**(-1/3)*(v1)**2/(st3)**2
            p=1-(Sch/Sch_crit)
            if abs(p) > 1.0:
                p=1.0
            w_s=dm**2*9.807*(rou_s-rou_w)/(18*nou*rou_w)
            sed_rate=abs(p)*w_s*K
            area = float(column4[0])
            sed = sed_rate * 3600 *area
            print("{:.6f}".format(sediment), file=outfile4)
            print("{:.2f}".format(Schub), file=outfile)
            print("{:.2f}".format(abs(p)), file=outfile2)
            print("{:.6f}".format(sediment_rate), file=outfile3)
            #outfile.write("%.2f\t %.2f\n" % (vx,vy))
    except ValueError:
            print(line2, file=outfile4)
            print(line2, file=outfile)
            print(line2, file=outfile2)
            print(line2, file=outfile3)
```

*************************Edit***********************

Summary: I have this inputfile

```
Timestep 1000
Y TESFG 1
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
Timestep 1001
Y TESFG 1
2.0
2.0
2.0
2.0
Timestep 1002
Y TESFG 1
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.2
```

I want to get this:

```
Timestep all
Y TESFG 1
4.0
4.0
4.0
4.2
```

**************Edit*****************

Here is my second question!

I want to have an accumulation data output so that for each timestep it checks the accumulative value of the data and if it is greater than a max value. it stops the addition for that specific line. so in example above, if the max value is 3.0, the last time step won't be added and the result will be:

```
Timestep all
Y TESFG 1
3.0
3.0
3.0
3.0
```

Comment: 'Y TESFG 1' and 'Y TESFG' these two different are same?. In your expected output it only has 'Y TESFG 1'. Show how the data stored in each file

Comment: The lines with text wich cannot be convert into float will be taken from input file 2. Anyway these Texts are not important for my caluclations. It can be taken from other inpout files. My main problem is to have am method not to storing the whole data.

Comment: My input has many timesteps. My output should have just one timestep with the summation of all timesteps for each line. And the example of my input and output is in the question (see question above)

Comment: Yes! all of timesteps are in one file. I have added an Edit with a summary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
with open('input.txt') as fp:
    data = [float(line.strip()) for line in fp if line.strip().replace('.', '', 1).isdigit()]

mmax = 3.0
data = [data[i: i+4] for i in range(0, len(data), 4)]
res =  'Timestep all\nY TESFG 1\n' + '\n'.join([str(sum(x)) if sum(x) < mmax else str(mmax) for x in map(list, zip(*data))])
print(res)
```

**Ouput:**

```
Timestep all
Y TESFG 1
3.0
3.0
3.0
3.0
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I wanted to know if there is a way to put an if in that list comperhension so that it can compare sum(x) if it is reached a maximum just write for that line the maximum at the end!

Comment: do you mean max number in each line?

Comment: I mean, the accumulative sum of number in each line. For example, if the max_value is 3.0 for the code above. Before summation it checks with that value and at the end the result will be 3.0 for all lines.

Comment: Can you give an example

Comment: Is that max_value always fixed?

Comment: Yes. it is fixed